# the difference between doMC and doParallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, domc, doparallel

What's the difference between `doParallel` and `doMC` in R concerning `foreach` function? `doParallel` supports windows, unix-like, while `doMC` supports unix-like only. In other words, why `doParallel` cannot replace `doMC` directly? Thank you.

Update:
`doParallel` is built on `parallel`, which is essentially a merger of `multicore` and `snow` and automatically uses the appropriate tool for your system. As a result, we can use `doParallel` to support multi systems. In other words, we can use `doParallel` to replace `doMC`.

ref: http://michaeljkoontz.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/9/4/19940979/parallel.pdf

BTW, what is the difference between `registerDoParallel(ncores=3)` and

```
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

It seems `registerDoParallel(ncores=3)` can stop cluster automatically, while the second do not stop automatically and needs `stopCluster(cl)`.

ref: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: just so that the two get linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829300/doparallel-cluster-vs-cores?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doParallel, cluster vs cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829300/doparallel-cluster-vs-cores)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `doParallel` package is a merger of `doSNOW` and `doMC`, much as `parallel` is a merger of `snow` and `multicore`. But although `doParallel` has all the features of `doMC`, I was told by Rich Calaway of Revolution Analytics that they wanted to keep `doMC` around because it was more efficient in certain circumstances, even though `doMC` now uses `parallel` just like `doParallel`. I haven't personally run any benchmarks to determine if and when there is a significant difference.

I tend to use `doMC` on a Linux or Mac OS X computer, `doParallel` on a Windows computer, and `doMPI` on a Linux cluster, but `doParallel` does work on all of those platforms.

---

As for the different registration methods, if you execute:

```
registerDoParallel(cores=3)
```

on a Windows machine, it will create a cluster object implicitly for later use with `clusterApplyLB`, whereas on Linux and Mac OS X, no cluster object is created or used. The number of cores is simply remembered and used as the value of the `mc.cores` argument later when calling `mclapply`.

If you execute:

```
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

then the registered cluster object will be used with `clusterApplyLB` regardless of the platform. You are correct that in this case, it is your responsibility to shutdown the cluster object since you created it, whereas the implicit cluster object is automatically shutdown.

Comment: Are there words or documents about "the certain circumstances" for `doMC` from Rich Calaway of Revolution Analytics? In addition, is there any difference considering performance in the `ncores` and `makeCluster` situation? I developed a R [cogena](https://github.com/zhilongjia/cogena) package where parallel was copied with `doMC` originally. I just changed it to `doParallel` to support Windows few hours ago. It's a litter complex concerning `NAMESPACE` and `import` when implemented via mix of `doMC` and `doParallel`. Thank you.

Comment: @Zhilong In an R package, I think you should let the end user register whatever backend works best on their hardware. That makes your code simpler and more flexible. That was the original intent of separating out the backend and is the way that caret and plyr do it, for example.

Comment: I've gotten your idea. Thank you. If there are performance difference in general machine, I will do as you suggested. If not, I prefer my package is easy to use so far. I emailed the Maintainer of `doParallel` and will keep you update.

Comment: Here is the reply from Rich of Revolution Analytics (sorry, a litter long for comment on SO, I just paste the conclusion):  "I recommend doParallel for most new users, because it is supported on both Linux and Windows and uses the built-in parallel package. Further, I recommend using the fork cluster feature of parallel and the snow-like interface to avoid zombie processes on Linux."

Comment: Typo: the option is called `cores` not `ncores`. It wouldn't let me edit your answer with less than 6 characters.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Thanks. I fixed it in my answer.