# What is the best practice for making functions in my R package parallelizable?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-package, parallel-foreach

I have developed an R package that contains [embarassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) functions.

I would like to implement parallelization for these functions in a way that is  transparent to the user, regardless of his/her OS (at least ideally).

I have looked around to see how other package authors have imported [foreach-based Parallelism](http://www.glennklockwood.com/data-intensive/r/foreach-parallelism.html).  For example, Max Kuhn's `caret` package imports `foreach` to use `%dopar%` but [relies](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/36f8216a1f18e17021adfd17ebdffa8e9f058949/bookdown/08-Parallel.Rmd)  on the user to specify a parallel backend. (Several examples use `doMC`, which doesn't work on Windows.)

Noting that [doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/index.html) works for Windows and Linux/OSX and uses the built-in `parallel` package (see comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001039/2573061) for useful discussion), does it make sense to import `doParallel` and have my functions call `registerDoParallel()` whenever the user specifies `parallel=TRUE` as an argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's very important to allow the user to register their own parallel backend. The `doParallel` backend is very portable, but what if they want to run your function on multiple nodes of a cluster? What if they want to set the `makeCluster` "outfile" option? It's unfortunate if making the parallel support transparent also makes it useless for many of your users.

I suggest that you use the `getDoParRegistered` function to see if the user has already registered a parallel backend, and only register one for them if they haven't.

Here's an example:

```
library(doParallel)
parfun <- function(n=10, parallel=FALSE,
                   cores=getOption('mc.cores', 2L)) {
  if (parallel) {
    # honor registration made by user, and only create and register
    # our own cluster object once
    if (! getDoParRegistered()) {
      cl <- makePSOCKcluster(cores)
      registerDoParallel(cl)
      message('Registered doParallel with ',
              cores, ' workers')
    } else {
      message('Using ', getDoParName(), ' with ',
              getDoParWorkers(), ' workers')
    }
    `%d%` <- `%dopar%`
  } else {
    message('Executing parfun sequentially')
    `%d%` <- `%do%`
  }

  foreach(i=seq_len(n), .combine='c') %d% {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    i
  }
}
```

This is written so that it only runs in parallel if `parallel=TRUE`, even if they registered a parallel backend:

```
> parfun()
Executing parfun sequentially
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If `parallel=TRUE` and they haven't registered a backend, then it will create and register a cluster object for them:

```
> parfun(parallel=TRUE, cores=3)
Registered doParallel with 3 workers
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If `parfun` is called with `parallel=TRUE` again, it will use the previously registered cluster:

```
> parfun(parallel=TRUE)
Using doParallelSNOW with 3 workers
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

This can be refined in many ways: it's just a simple demonstration. But at least it provides a convenience without preventing users from registering a different backend with custom options that might be necessary in their environment.

---

Note that the choice of a default number of cores/workers is also a tricky issue, and one that the CRAN maintainers care about. That is why I didn't make the default number of cores `detectCores()`. Instead, I'm using the method used by `mclapply`, although perhaps a different option name should be used.

---

*Concerning `stopCluster`*

Note that this example will sometimes create a new cluster object, but it never stops it via a call to `stopCluster`. The reason is that creating cluster objects can be expensive, so I like to reuse them for multiple foreach loops, rather than create and destroy them each time. I'd rather leave that to the user, however, in this example, there isn't a way for the user to do that, since they don't have access to the `cl` variable.

There are three ways to handle this:

- Call `stopCluster` in `parfun` whenever `makePSOCKcluster` is called;
- Write an additional function that allows the user to stop the implicitly created cluster object (equivalent to the `stopImplicitCluster` function in the `doParallel` package);
- Don't worry about the implicitly created cluster object.

I would probably choose the second option for my own code, but that would significantly complicate this example. It's already rather complicated.

Comment: This looks like the right balance of support for easy, built-in parallelization and support for more advanced users.  Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: How would you stopCluster(cl) then? Leave it up to the user?

Comment: @JPMac How about `on.exit(stopCluster(cl))` after `cl <- makePSOCKcluster(cores)`

Comment: @JPMac I updated my answer to address the issue of `stopCluster`.

Answer (score 5):

As the author of the future package, I recommend that you look at it. The future package unifies all of parallel's parallel / cluster functions into a single API.

https://cran.r-project.org/package=future

It is designed such that you as a developer *write your code once* and the user decides on the back end, e.g. `plan(multiprocess)`, `plan(cluster, workers = c("n1", "n3", "remote.server.org"))` etc.

If user ha s access to an HPC cluster with one of the common schedulers such as Slurm, TORQUE / PBS, and SGE, then they can use the future.BatchJobs package which implements the future API on top of BatchJobs, e.g. `plan(batchjobs_slurm)`. Your code remains the same.  (There soon will also be future.batchtools package on top of batchtools)).