# Cannot allocate memory even after deleting large objects and closing connections

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm encountering an intermittent error message in R after using parallel::dopar.

I use a dopar loop once after starting a fresh session and everything works. My script runs, takes a corpus, transforms it and outputs a matrix.

If I `rm(list = ls())` and `closeAllConnections()` I am unable to do anything after that without hitting a memory error.

Tried to run the function again with slightly altered parameters gave `"Error in mcfork() : unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory"` but then if I try to do ANYTHING else I get an error. I tried to type `sessionInfo()` which gave `"Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'uname' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'"`

I tried opening the shell in R studio (hosted R studio tools > shell) which gives a popup "cannot allocate memory".

I tried entering `stopImplicitCluster()` after my dopar loop as well as `closeAllConnections()`

I don't know where to look next? Does this sound familiar to anyone?

I noticed in the terminal top > 1 where I see each core that all my cores are at 100% sleeping but I'm not sure what that means. Here's a screen shot:
[image]

Not sure what other information to provide?

This is the script that runs perfectly fine once in a fresh session, then seems to leave me with no memory.

```
clean_corpus <- function(corpus, n = 1000) { # n is length of each peice in parallel processing

  # split the corpus into pieces for looping to get around memory issues with transformation
  nr <- length(corpus)
  pieces <- split(corpus, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))
  lenp <- length(pieces)

  rm(corpus) # save memory

  # save pieces to rds files since not enough RAM
  tmpfile <- tempfile() 
  for (i in seq_len(lenp)) {
    saveRDS(pieces[[i]],
            paste0(tmpfile, i, ".rds"))
  }

  rm(pieces) # save memory since now these are saved in tmp rds files

  # doparallel
  registerDoParallel(cores = 12)
  pieces <- foreach(i = seq_len(lenp)) %dopar% {
    # update spelling
    piece <- readRDS(paste0(tmpfile, i, ".rds"))
    # spelling update based on lut
    piece <- tm_map(piece, function(i) stringi_spelling_update(i, spellingdoc))
    # regular transformations
    piece <- tm_map(piece, removeNumbers)
    piece <- tm_map(piece, content_transformer(removePunctuation), preserve_intra_word_dashes = T)
    piece <- tm_map(piece, content_transformer(function(x, ...) 
      qdap::rm_stopwords(x, stopwords = tm::stopwords("english"), separate = F)))
    saveRDS(piece, paste0(tmpfile, i, ".rds"))
    return(1) # hack to get dopar to forget the piece to save memory since now saved to rds
  } 

  stopImplicitCluster() # I added this but according to documentation I don;t think I need to since implicit clusters are closed automatically by doparallel?

  # combine the pieces back into one corpus
  corpus <- list()
  corpus <- foreach(i = seq_len(lenp)) %do% {
    corpus[[i]] <- readRDS(paste0(tmpfile, i, ".rds"))
  }
  corpus <- do.call(function(...) c(..., recursive = TRUE), corpus)
  return(corpus)

} # end clean_corpus function
```

Comment: Kill the R processes. Then study the example in ´help("registerDoParallel")` and use it as a template for setting up and stoping the cluster.

Comment: You have no free swap left and most of RAM is in use.

Comment: Hi, on the screen shot how can you tell I have no free swap and most RAM is in use? Under %mem it says 52%.  How do you know about swap from the screen? I'll try changing my code to match the example in ```helpdoparallel()``` but from reading their documentation I thought my approach was sound?

Comment: Your main R process uses 52.3 % of memory. I assume there are other R processes (the workers). Try sorting by memory usage. I looked at the two lines after the CPU table (although I might interpret it wrong, I'm not an advanced linux user).

Comment: Looking at help("registerDoParallel") the example creates a cluster using ```cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)```. Do I need a cluster though? I'm using hosted R studio on a single server? Are clusters diferent from cores? My understanding was that I just need to use multiple cores on a single machine. A posted about this previously. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779447/do-i-still-need-to-makecluster-if-im-already-doing-registerdoparallelcl/45799904?noredirect=1#comment78558415_45799904

Comment: On top of that, manually creating a cluster using makeCluster means you have to export all needed objects to the cluster, so for convenience is using just registerDoParallel() not simpler and just as efficient? I'm not sure

Comment: A "cluster" can be on one computer. Also, the objects need to be exported anyway. The only difference is that you created the cluster implicitly and have consequently less control over it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info but... what's the benefit of doing this if registerdoparallel() takes care of exporting and closing for you?

Comment: Are you sure the child processes are closed? I suspect they aren't. Check that.

Comment: I don't know how to close them, I'm researching that now. My understanding was that doparallel woud take care of that but here it appears somehting is not working correctly

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-kill-a-process-in-linux/

Comment: Yeah I already killed the rsession PID the problem I think is these child sleepers which are remaining and won't die

Comment: Have you sorted the top output by mem usage? Killing the main process does not kill child processes (if they are indeed still there).

Comment: I did that just now. All show zero except every now and then PID 127591 uses 0.3% memory. I tried this command to see if I could kill it ```pkill -TERM -P 127591``` but the sleeping process are still there

Comment: I might repost this question more specifically to doparallel leaving sleeping process'. What do you think? It might narrow it down a  bit

Comment: I'm not at all sure that you actually have sleeping R processes.

Comment: Oh hang on, I've misread the screen shot. I was looking at all the values of 100 which appear under the text "sleeping". But sleeping is not a column. These are 100% id... idle?